# Transparency issue on IE with BlendColor filter

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, fabricjs

Here a little demo where I use the filter BlendColor from the framework Fabric.js to make an image blue.

https://jsfiddle.net/w2kdcs21/7/

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

fabric.Image.fromURL(document.getElementById('logo').src, function(img) {
  img.filters.push(
    new fabric.Image.filters.BlendColor({
        color: '#222299',
      mode: 'tint'
    })
  );

  img.applyFilters();
  canvas.add(img);
});


// create a rectangle with angle=45
var rect = new fabric.Rect({
  left: 50,
  top: 50,
  fill: 'red',
  width: 100,
  height: 100
});
canvas.add(rect);
```

https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/issues/4715

**Expected Behavior**

The transparent area of the PNG should remain transparent.

**Actual Behavior**

On in IE or Edge, the transparent area of the PNG is not fully transparent anymore and a part of the red square is now pink.

Any leads are welcome, thanks!

Comment: I think it might be a bug/browser difference of the alpha channels in the IE. This is where the source of the bug may be https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/blob/debf1ec069c46df8e211960a039814a8ac8d2ca8/src/filters/blendcolor_filter.class.js#L178. But unfortunately JSfiddle site itself is not working well in my IE11 VM to see what value is there for this in case of both the browsers

Comment: The issue is webgl only, and that line is outside webgl context

Comment: @AndreaBogazzi, I had looked at the code you modified, but I had no idea if it is even executed or was for reference (comments). Have no idea on WebGL. Glad you provided a fix. +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the problem here is some crappy Microsoft webgl support.
We have 2 cases, EDGE and IE11.

IE11 has premultiplied alpha always set to true, while EDGE looks like it supports the parameter, but the bug is there anyway.

[image: example of the error]

The texture gets some kind of soft alpha bluish

I managed to fix the issue modifying the shader for each filter, i think at expense of performance for each browser.

The difference is from this:

```
  tint: 'precision highp float;\n' +
    'uniform sampler2D uTexture;\n' +
    'uniform vec4 uColor;\n' +
    'varying vec2 vTexCoord;\n' +
    'void main() {\n' +
      'gl_FragColor = texture2D(uTexture, vTexCoord);\n' +
      'gl_FragColor.rgb *= (1.0 - uColor.a);\n' +
      'gl_FragColor.rgb += uColor.rgb;\n' +
    '}'
```

to this:

```
  tint: 'precision highp float;\n' +
    'uniform sampler2D uTexture;\n' +
    'uniform vec4 uColor;\n' +
    'varying vec2 vTexCoord;\n' +
    'void main() {\n' +
      'vec4 color = texture2D(uTexture, vTexCoord);\n' +
      'gl_FragColor = color;\n' +
      'if (color.a > 0.0) {\n' +
        'gl_FragColor.rgb *= (1.0 - uColor.a);\n' +
        'gl_FragColor.rgb += uColor.rgb;\n' +
        'gl_FragColor.a = color.a;\n' +
      '}\n' +
    '}'
```

I'll try to push up a release out as soon as possible.